# Теряется фокусировка на кастомном Entry

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Пишу приложение для телефона со встроенным qr-сканером. Суть в том что при сканировании в Entry приходил номер и по этому номеру происходил поиск по базе и вывод в Label, при это клавиатура не должна открывать. Проблема заключается в том, что все происходит хорошо, до того как приходят данные в Label, курсор в Entry горит, но второй раз подряд взаимодействовать с ним не получается.
Код из MainPage

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string id = Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver,
            Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId); // Id устройства
        }
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            SoftkeyboardDisabledEntry.Focus();
        }
        public void SoftkeyboardDisabledEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Poisk();
            // Установка фокуса при загрузке страницы
            SoftkeyboardDisabledEntry.Focused += Entry_Focused;
        }
        public void Poisk()
        {
            string connnn = " ";
            MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection(connnn);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string ind_num = SoftkeyboardDisabledEntry.Text;
                string sql = " ";
                MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ind_num", ind_num);
                MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Art.Text = reader[22].ToString();
                    Date.Text = reader[46].ToString();
                    string status = reader[8].ToString();
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(status) < 2)
                    {
                        Status.Text = "Бла бла бла";
                        Status.TextColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToInt32(status) >= 2)
                    {
                        Status.Text = "Принят";
                        Status.TextColor = Color.Blue;
                    }
                    DateTime DT = DateTime.Now;
                    DateTime dateToCompare;
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(Date.Text, out dateToCompare))
                    {
                        if (dateToCompare.Date == DT.Date)
                        {
                            Date.TextColor = Color.Blue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Date.TextColor = Color.Red;
                        }
                    }
                    Date.Text = dateToCompare.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");   
                }
                SoftkeyboardDisabledEntry.Text = string.Empty;                
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        public void Entry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            SoftkeyboardDisabledEntry.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Код из класса SoftkeyboardDisabledEntryRenderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SoftkeyboardDisabledEntry), typeof(SoftkeyboardDisabledEntryRenderer))]
namespace ScannerTUBOG.Droid
{
    [Obsolete]
    public class SoftkeyboardDisabledEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                ((SoftkeyboardDisabledEntry)e.NewElement).PropertyChanging += OnPropertyChanging;
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                ((SoftkeyboardDisabledEntry)e.OldElement).PropertyChanging -= OnPropertyChanging;
            }
            this.Control.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
            if (Control != null && e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
                Control.SetTextIsSelectable(true);
            }
        }
        private void OnPropertyChanging(object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs propertyChangingEventArgs)
        {
            if (propertyChangingEventArgs.PropertyName == VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.Control.WindowToken, 0);
                Control.RequestFocus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```